# ajax call in jsf with popup window

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

Below is my code in .xhtml file.  I need to add ajax call in one of the inputtextbox component. Say.. on blur of inputtextbox where id="search_dias" i should make ajax call with popup window showing the response value and then i should place that value in inputTextBox where id="search_partyName"

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  
    <h:form>
        <p:panel id="panel1" styleClass ="myPanelStyle1"  header="SEARCH PRODUCTIONS " toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="100">
          <h:panelGrid columns="3" border="0" rules="group">
                  <p:column >
                     <h:outputLabel  for="search_dia" value="Diameter:"/>
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column>
                     <p:inputText  id="search_dias" value="#{addFormRequest.diameter}"/>
                  </p:column>
                  <p:tooltip for="search_dias" value="Enter Dia Value" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />
                  <p:column >
                     <h:outputLabel for="search_partyName" value="PartyName:"/>              
                  </p:column>
                  <p:column>
                     <p:inputText  id="search_partyName" value="#{addFormRequest.search_partyName}"/> 
                  </p:column>
                  <p:tooltip for="search_partyName" value="Enter Party Name" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" /> 
                  <p:column >
                     <h:outputLabel for="search_date" value="Date:"/>
                  </p:column>
                  <p:calendar  id="search_date" value="#{addFormRequest.search_date}"/>
                  <p:tooltip for="search_date" value="Enter Production Date" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" /> 
                  <p:commandButton id="searchProductions" value="SEARCH" action="search"  />
              </h:panelGrid>
         </p:panel>  
  </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers can be found here:

- [Show dialog on dataTable row selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf)
- [Inputtext blur event](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxifyKeyEvents.jsf)
- [Show dialog on ajax event in dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922306/primefaces-dialog-does-not-show)

Comment: @Apprentice.. Is it possible to make ajax call for inputtextbox?

Comment: @Apprentice.. my requirement is blur of 1 st inputText box i have to call method by passing the (1 st inputText) value as param for some manipulation and the return value should be placed in the (2nd inputText)

Comment: 1.Yes, it is possible. Example:
<p:inputText id="inputOne" value="#{bean.valueOne}">  
  <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{bean.someAction}" update="inputTwo" />  
</p:inputText>  
<p:inputText  id="inputTwo" value="#{bean.valueTwo}"/>
In someAction method you just read valueOne, manipulate it and change valueTwo. If you want to show dialog, you add: oncomplete="PF('dialogName').show()" to your ajax tag.

Comment: I have created someAction(AjaxBehavourEvent) method in FormBean(SearchFormRequest) its getting invoked onblur of 1st inputtext box but how to return data from that someAction() method.Note: im doing ajax call for checking record is present or not by entering "id value" in 1st input,if exist im prepopulating the other fields otherwise im adding new data values in other inputText box.