# What does the PF function do in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

On many places one can find usage of a function `PF` with Primefaces. For example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922306/primefaces-dialog-does-not-show)

From what I have seen so far it seems to be a magic "make it work a little better" function. But I don't believe in this kind of stuff so:

What does this function do?

And where can I find documentation about it?

Comment: Whoa good question why didnt i think of that .... :O

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`PF` is a Javascript function.

In Primefaces 4.0 the Javascript scope of widgets changed. Prior to version 4.0 you could open a dialog widget with `widgetVar.show();`.

In Primefaces 4.0 and above the widgets are stored in a Javascript widget array.  When you call PF('widgetVar') it is looking for the widget in the array and returning it.

```
PF=function(d){
    var c=b.widgets[d];
    if(!c){
        if(a.console&&console.log){
            console.log("Widget for var '"+d+"' not available!")
        }
        b.error("Widget for var '"+d+"' not available!")
    }
    return c
};
```

I could not find much on this either this is what I was able to decipher using Chrome's developer tools.

Answer (score 24):

The `PF` function is a part of PrimeFaces's JavaScript API. It looks up a Javascript object that is the backbone of the JSF component on the client-side. Here is its definition ([source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js)):

```
PF = function(widgetVar) {      
        var widgetInstance = PrimeFaces.widgets[widgetVar];

        if (!widgetInstance) {
            PrimeFaces.error("Widget for var '" + widgetVar + "' not available!");
        }

        return widgetInstance;
    };
```

`PF` is a shortcut for `PrimeFaces.widgets['someWidgetId']`, which just looks-up a Javascript object in global scope, and so the Javascript object can also be retrieved using `window['someWidgetId']`.

The PrimeFaces's Javascript API has no official documentation online, so to understand what you can really "do" with the Javascript object, you'll need to take a deep dive into PrimeFaces.

#### See also

- ["Intro To PrimeFaces widgetVar" blog post](http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/)
- [PrimeFaces source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/core/core.js#L711)

Comment: I'm not certain this adds much to what Mark said, but I'll leave that for you to decide.

Comment: Imo it does. Better references and hence my upvote  (Deciphering an opensource project with a browser developer tool ;-) ) but you better change the reference to the source to github since they moved recently

Answer (score 10):

For other Primefaces users coming here when upgrading to version 4.0 and above, it's possible to bypass the need to use `PF('yourWidgetVar').someFunction()` and just use `yourWidgetVar.someFunction()` directly as you would have before version 4.0. You just need the following configuration in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.LEGACY_WIDGET_NAMESPACE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

From the Primefaces User Guide:

> Enables window scope so that widgets can be accessed using
>   widgetVar.method() in addition to default PF namespace approach like
>   PF('widgetVar').method().

Obviously you'd be susceptible to the namespace clash/pollution this feature was created to avoid, but it's useful if you want to migrate to a new version in little steps and isolate what incompatibilities the new version has introduced.

Comment: Awesome! this saved me from updating my whole codebase while my project is on a very tight timeline! Thanks