# Controlling primefaces dialog from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I try to control primefaces display show and hide from java script on bean validation failure, but its not working. As suggested in forums have tried 
with widgetVar name of the component in javascript and even tried with id of the component but failed.

**XHTML**

```
<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" id="mglasspaneid" showHeader="false" closable="true" resizable="false" draggable="false" widgetVar="mglasspane" style="height: 50px !important;" modal="true">
        <span id="loading" draggable="false" style="height: auto !important;">Loading</span>
</p:dialog>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
        function handleComplete(data) {
            if (data.status === 'success') { 

               console.log(document.getElementById('validation-failed').value);
               mglasspane.hide();

            }else{
                console.log(document.getElementById('validation-failed').value);
                mglasspane.show();
            }                
        }
</script>
```

Comment: any javascript errors? And what PF version?

Comment: @Kukeltje Primefaces 5.2,Error: ReferenceError : mglasspane is not defined

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get primefaces widgetVar in javascript and update it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609536/get-primefaces-widgetvar-in-javascript-and-update-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PrimeFaces 5.0 you must call any component with the `PF` function (i.e. `PF('widgtVar')` instead of `widgetVar` which has already been deprecated in 4.0). Source [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=37429).

Replacing `mglasspane.hide();` by `PF('mglasspane').hide();` should work.

---

More information about the `PF` function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679367/what-does-the-pf-function-do-in-primefaces)