# Primefaces 5.2 calendar is undefined

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm upgrading my version of Primefaces from 3.0.1 to 5.2. 
I'm now with myFaces 2.2.8 and Primefaces 5.2. This upgrade broke my primefaces calendar and I cannot figure what happened :

I'm using : `widgetVar="calendar"` in my `p:calendar` but I cannot access the javascript variable `calendar` any more.

Here is my sample page :

```
    <h:body>
    <p:calendar popupIconOnly="true"
                showOn="button"
                id="validityCalendar"
                locale="fr" 
                navigator="true"
                disabledWeekends="true" 
                style="padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;"
                widgetVar="calendar" size="10" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
    calendar.jqEl.datepicker("option", {maxDate : "11/07/2016", onChangeMonthYear : onChangeMonthYear});
   });
   </script>
</h:body>
```

And I get this error :

```
ReferenceError: calendar is not defined
```

I do not include another jquery or jquery-ui than the one of Primefaces.
The `popupIconOnly` does not work either but this is another topic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ReferenceError: calendar is not defined

From PrimeFaces 4.0 you need to use PF('widgetVar') instead of widgetVar, i.e. `PF('calendar')`.

- [What does the PF function do in Primefaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679367/what-does-the-pf-function-do-in-primefaces)

> The popupIconOnly does not work either but this is another topic...

`popupIconOnly` attribute has been removed from PrimeFaces 5.0

- https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7430

Comment: Thanks, did not find this information anywhere else... And PF doc should be updated for the "popupIconOnly"