# Change default behavior of p:confirmDialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need change default behavior of p:confirmDialog. On click at yes button, it has completed the request passing value 1, on click at no, it has completed a request passing value 0.

```
    <p:commandButton value="Consultar"  onclick="consultar.show()">  
    <p:confirmDialog id="consultar" message="Foi feito a venda de recarga para esse cliente?" header="Confirmação" severity="alert" widgetVar="consultar">  
        <p:commandButton id="confirmaBtn" value="Sim" oncomplete="consultar.hide()" action="#{notaFiscalBean.consultarNota}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{notaFiscalBean.temRecarga}" value="1" />    
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton id="recusaBtn" value="Não" oncomplete="consultar.hide()" action="#{notaFiscalBean.consultarNota}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{notaFiscalBean.temRecarga}" value="0" />
        </p:commandButton>   
    </p:confirmDialog>
</p:commandButton>
```

This solution doesn't work. Anyone have an idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Please, could you put the Bean action code too?

Comment: The answer below, solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-Global mode is almost same as the dialog component used with a simple client side api, show() and hide(). Reference Primefaces USER GUIDE 5.3 Page 121.

```
<p:commandButton value="Consultar" onclick="PF('consultar').show()"></p:commandButton>
        <p:confirmDialog id="consultar"
            message="Foi feito a venda de recarga para esse cliente?"
            header="Confirmação" severity="alert" widgetVar="consultar">
            <p:commandButton id="confirmaBtn" value="Sim"
                oncomplete="PF('consultar').hide()"
                action="#{notaFiscalBean.consultarNota}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{notaFiscalBean.temRecarga}"
                    value="1" />
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton id="recusaBtn" value="Não"
                oncomplete="PF('consultar').hide()"
                action="#{notaFiscalBean.consultarNota}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{notaFiscalBean.temRecarga}"
                    value="0" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:confirmDialog>
```

[PF java script function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679367/what-does-the-pf-function-do-in-primefaces)

Tested with JSF 2.2.4 , Primefaces 5.3